# jQuery, checking an on click event

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML markup:

```
<ul class="am-type-con">
    <li><a id="Distributor" href="#tabs-1">Distributors UK</a></li>
    <li><a id="International" href="#tabs-2">International</a></li>
</ul>
```

I also have a DIV ID called `map-canvas`. If there has been an on click event on `International` I'd like to hide the `map-canvas` DIV. I'd like it to re-appear when `Distributor`is clicked. Is there a simple solution to this in jQuery? Thanks

This is what I have, but this is not working:

```
$("#International").click(function(){
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
});
if($('#International').data('clicked')) {
    $( '#map-canvas' ).remove();        
}
```

Comment: Sure, what have you tried?

Comment: Helps to see your attempt then we can see your mistakes and correct them - not going to flat code it for you.

Comment: I've included what I have so far, sorry I had made an effort just forgot to include in my haste

Answer (score 2):

Try the following JS code:

```
$('#International').click(function() {
  $('#map-canvas').hide();
});

$('#Distributor').click(function() {
  $('#map-canvas').show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#International').click(function() {
    $('#map-canvas').hide();
});

$('#Distributor').click(function() {
    $('#map-canvas').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
$('#International').on('click',function() {
   $('#map-canvas').hide();
});

$('#Distributor').on('click',function() {
   $('#map-canvas').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See [JQuery Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
     var $mapcanv = $('#map-canvas'); //global scope
      $("#International").on('click',function(){

         if ($mapcanv.is(":visible")) {
           $mapcanv.hide();
         }
     });

      $('#Distributor').on('click',function() {

           if ($mapcanv.is(":hidden")) {
              $mapcanv.show();
            }
      });
```

Comment: Your answer has **nothing** to do with event delegation.

Comment: Correct, I am not delegating to any particular element. It was for steering the OP in the direction of researching and hopefully utilizing event delegation his jQuery events.

Comment: OK, I guess thats understandable if utilizing it would help him in any way. I was just confused since it seemed to have no relation to the question that was asked. I just fail to see how researching event delegation helps him hide and show something when clicking. He should first understand events and how they work before beginning to understand what delegation is and when its useful.

Comment: "He should first understand events and how they work..." - I understand your point. I was simply wanting to point him to the best practice first while learning about events rather than learn the basics, then having to go and learn the better way to do it. I prefer to learn the better way to do things while learning the basics, so I do the right thing the first time. My preference though